# What could be blocking spoofed UDP packets on Windows computer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, udp, raw-sockets

I tried to create a simple IP address spoofing program. The goal is to convince computer game on local network to connect to an internet server. The game only discovers servers via UDP broadcast and won't accept server IP.

So instead I want to trick the game into thinking that it received answer info from the internet server by creating a fake UDP packet.

I successfully used `raw-socket` to generate IPV4 packet with UDP payload. As long as I set the correct IP it gets sent.

However, If I put fake IP in the packet, it won't get out of the machine. I can't see it in Wireshark on my machine. I also noticed that something corrects IPV4 checksums on my packet. I always send checksum `0xFFFF`, but Wireshark sees this:

[image]

How I send it using `raw-socket`:

```
const raw = require("raw-socket");
const UDPPacket = require("../generic/UDPPacket");
const IPV4Packet = require("../generic/IPV4Packet");

var socket = raw.createSocket({ protocol: raw.Protocol.UDP });

socket.on("message", function (buffer, source) {
    console.log("received " + buffer.length + " bytes from " + source);
});
// UDPPacket and IPV4 packet are classes that I wrote in order to 
// generate the UDP and IPV4 byte data
const packet = new UDPPacket();
packet.srcPort = 27888;
packet.dstPort = 1234;
packet.data = responseBuffer;
const buf = packet.fullBuffer;
const ipv4packet = new IPV4Packet();
ipv4packet.payloadBuffer = buf;

// I send the message form several IPs, but only mine works
const iprand = "192.168.110.";
let ipincrement = 75 * 2;
// my actual IP right now
ipv4packet.srcAddr = "192.168.110.79";
ipv4packet.dstAddr = "192.168.110.1";


setInterval(() => {
    // Try to send it from another IP
    ipv4packet.srcAddr = iprand + Math.round((++ipincrement)/2);
    const ipv4buf = ipv4packet.fullBuffer;
    socket.send(ipv4buf, 0, ipv4buf.length, ipv4packet.dstAddr, function (error, bytes) {
        // I'm not sure what does this exactly do,
        // I found it on the internet ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
        // But without it, I cannot send the IPV4 headers
        socket.setOption(
            raw.SocketLevel.IPPROTO_IP,
            raw.SocketOption.IP_HDRINCL,
            new Buffer([0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]),
            4
        );
    },
    function (error, bytes) {
        // always prints that bytes were sent
        if (error)
            console.log(error.toString());
        else
            console.log(bytes, " bytes sent!");
    }
    );
}, 700)
```

Who is blocking and changing my packets? I tried disabling firewall, didn't help.

Note that the messages are getting lost EVEN IF THE TARGET IS THE LOCAL MACHINE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx:

On Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2), and Windows XP with Service Pack 3 (SP3), the ability to send traffic over raw sockets has been restricted in several ways:

UDP datagrams with an invalid source address cannot be sent over raw sockets. The IP source address for any outgoing UDP datagram must exist on a network interface or the datagram is dropped. This change was made to limit the ability of malicious code to create distributed denial-of-service attacks and limits the ability to send spoofed packets (TCP/IP packets with a forged source IP address).

Comment: Surely, there must be a workaround, at least for spoofing packets within my own computer only.